# Animate Gradient colors on the line in C# .net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, animation, gradient

Imagine I have a line which is colored Gradient with three color : dark red, red and light red. I want to change position of these colors in that line . My purpose is showing something is moving along line. 
I don't know How I can create animation for changing position of each colors in a line which is colored gradient.

[image]

I have found this : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-animate-the-position-or-color-of-a-gradient-stop

but It isn't too clear.

Comment: In winforms you can use a LinearGradientBrush and move the starting point outward in a Tick event..

Comment: I added it. @TaW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

[image]

It uses a `LineraGradientBrush`, moving the starting point of the defining rectangle top left and painting a **rotated** rectangle onto a `PictureBox`:

```
Point p1 = Point.Empty;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int deltaX = -3;
    int deltaY = -3;
    p1 = new Point(p1.X + deltaX , p1.Y + deltaY); // roll..
    if (p1.X < deltaX * 1000) p1 = Point.Empty;    // ..around
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();

}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    float angle = 33f;
    if (!timer1.Enabled) return;
    Rectangle rectG = new Rectangle(p1.X, p1.Y, 122, 22);
    Rectangle rectR = new Rectangle(22, 22, 222, 22);
    LinearGradientBrush lBrush = new LinearGradientBrush(rectG, 
                                     Color.Red, Color.Red, angle, false);

    ColorBlend cblend = new ColorBlend(5);
    cblend.Colors = new Color[5]  
         { Color.Red, Color.Pink, Color.MistyRose, Color.LightCoral, Color.White };
    cblend.Positions = new float[5] { 0f, 0.2f, 0.5f, 0.8f, 1f };
    lBrush.InterpolationColors = cblend;
    lBrush.WrapMode = WrapMode.TileFlipXY;

    e.Graphics.RotateTransform(angle);
    e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(22,11);
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(lBrush, rectR);
}
```

Note that this being Winforms you can't get real smooth animations but if the control/form you paint on is `DoubleBufered` at least it won't flicker..